# Linux running snmpcheck.pl -t 10.100.10.254 | less

Tags: linux, snmp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A6VV.png)Hello I need to run the command to find more details about snmp chek. this is for a computer science project. I am stuck since 2 days. I tried

./snmpcheck.pl -t 10.100.10.254 | less

but it doen't works any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

---

snmpcheck-1.8.pl http://www.nothink.org/codes/snmpcheck/snmpcheck-1.8.pl

```
$ ./snmpcheck-1.8.pl -t 10.100.10.254 | less
 snmpcheck.pl v1.8 - SNMP enumerator
Copyright (c) 2005-2011 by Matteo Cantoni (www.nothink.org)

 [*] Try to connect to 10.100.10.254
 [*] Connected to 10.100.10.254
 [*] Starting enumeration at 2015-11-09 13:38:34
 [*] Error: No response from remote host "10.100.10.254".
~
~
~
~
lines 1-7/7 (END)
```

Please try : $ ./snmpcheck-1.8.pl -t 10.100.10.254

---

[snmpcheck](/questions/tagged/snmpcheck)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is still not working .see picture. I think because it is in some other directory. Do you have some suggestion?.                                            user1437@shellexamn:~$ ./snmpchek-1.8.pl -t 10.100.254                          
-bash: ./snmpchek-1.8.pl: No such file or directory